# Show that $p(x)=rq(x)$ for some rational number $r$

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

> Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients. Suppose they have a non-rational zero in common. Show that $$p(x)=rq(x)$$ for some rational number $r$.

If the common root is an irrational number then the discriminant must be a positive non square integer. This is because all the coefficients are integers. Apart from this I can't think of anything else.

Is it worth trying to define $f(x)=p(x)-rq(x)$ and investigating the properties of $f(x)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? You are quite high reputated user to know about the working of this website. (-1)

Comment: @Henrik They have one root common. (Non-rational **zero** (Non-rational root) in common)

Comment: If there is one non-rational root, can the other root be rational?

Comment: @Henrik The other root cannot be rational if the first is irrational. I've deduced that much. What next?

Comment: Factor the polynomials.

Comment: @Henrik I think I found a way but I don't think it's elegant. I can define the two polynomials as $p(x)=s(x-a)(x-b)$ and $q(x)=t(x-a)(x-c)$. Then I divide the former by the latter. One of the factors cancel. And the result that remains for $x \neq a$ is a rational number. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the Irrational Conjugate Roots Theorem (see [proof here](http://mathweb.scranton.edu/monks/courses/ProblemSolving/POLYTHEOREMS.pdf)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be the irrational root that is shared by $p$ and $q$. Then, by the
Irrational Conjugate Roots Theorem (#16 on [this list of polynomial theorems](https://monks.scranton.edu/files/courses/ProblemSolving/POLYTHEOREMS.pdf)), the irrational conjugate of $x_1$ must also be a root of both $p$ and $q$.

Explicitly, for any rational $a,b$ and irrational $\sqrt{c}$,  if $$x_1 = a + b\sqrt{c}$$ is a root of $p$, then $$x_2 = a - b\sqrt{c}$$ must also be a root. The same reasoning implies that $x_2$ is a root of $q$.

---

Since $p$ and $q$ are quadratics whose two roots are the same, they must be proportional, up to a constant. Since we have integer coefficients, the constant of proportionality $r$ must be rational, so we are done.

Comment: Can you update the link for the list of polynomial theorems?

Comment: Updated! Thanks for letting me know it was broken

Comment: OP says that the two polynomials have no roots in common. I am not sure about your statement "$x_2$ is a root of $q$".

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, since you know that they have a common root, you get that $gcd(p,q) \neq 1$.
Then, there exists $r,g \in F[X]$ with $deg(r),deg(g)<2$ so $p=rq+g$.

Now, write $r=ax+b$. Assume $a \neq 0$. Than since $p,q$ are noted that they both quadratic, you get that $p = rq+g$  where $rq+g$ is a polynomial of degree 3, therefore $a$ must be $0$.

You get that $r = b$ where $b \in \mathbb R$. But since all of the coefficients are integers, thus the coefficient of $x^2$ is integer, you get that $b \in \mathbb Q$ as needed.

Now, let us show that $g=0$. Since $p,q$ have only integer coefficients and $r$ is a rational number, $g$ must also have only integer coefficients.

Let us apply the common root on the equation $p=rq+g$. We get $g=0$ since it has only integer coeffients, thus proving $p=rq$.

Comment: Why does $\gcd(p,q) \neq 1$ imply the existence of $r$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I fixed the answer